# Displaying large graphs with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm using the `matplotlib` Python library to graph information about text. On my y-axis, I have a word, and on my x-axis, I have the number of times that word appears in the text. The thing is, with large pieces of text, the number of unique of words becomes undisplayable on a screen.

I'm currently using the PyCharm IDE and there is a helpful tool which shows my bar graph in its entirety, just zoomed out a lot. I can zoom into this graph and see all my data nicely.

My question is if there is a way to do such a thing with `matplotlib`. That is, make a graph such that in the case that there are too many words to display, it resizes and zooms out so that all the words do not overlap one another.

If there are any other means to display data such as mine in a better way, I would highly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: The easiest is to just set the limits of the y axis, e.g. `plt.ylim(-1, 20)` such that there are always only 20 entries shown.

Comment: What if I want to display all my data?

Comment: `plt.ylim(-1, len(all_y_data))`

Comment: Yes, ```plt.ylim(-1, 20)``` is a good solution. Thank you.

Comment: having a sample picture would help to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the figure size before plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(X, Y)
```